# Get current VAT rates in Europe

Tags: php, rate

I need to get the current VAT rates in PHP for every European country, eg 20% in France, 17% in Luxemburg.

There are website listing the VAT rates (Wikipedia) and I know rates don't change often but I need to be able to automatically update the rates.

Is there a URL source that I can check with cURL?

Comment: yup of course, wikipedia is one of it.. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_tax_rates and even http://www.uscib.org/valueadded-taxes-vat-ud-1676/

Comment: Check the below link it has the rates in json format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the direct JSON link for the VAT rates in Europe:

https://euvatrates.com/rates.json

https://vatlayer.com/

Hope it helps.